# how to copy text from xterm based terminal to some other gui application on linux

Tags: linux, copy-paste, xterm

i use uxrvt ( for those who dont know, its terminal emulator based on xterm).

i know its easy to copy/paste stuff from terminal to itself is a trivial thing. it can be done by mouse left click to select and middle click to paste.

but in my case i need to copy text from terminal to another application, viz on google chromium. how can i do that. is it even possible? anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way. Focus and then middle-click the control you want to paste into.

Comment: Remember that X11 has [_multiple_ "clipboards"](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html): selecting/Middle-click accesses the Primary selection, and using Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V accesses the Clipboard selection. (Shift-Insert _usually_ pastes from Primary.)